# Java Graphics g2

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that asks the user which shape they want to appear and then depending on that input, it will ask the dimensions of the shape and then show it in the window.  Im working on the first shape right now which is the square but i cannot seem to make it show up in the window.  I am posting the class i have for the square and my main method here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Square extends JComponent{

    private static int length; 

    public double getArea() {   
    return length * length;
    }
    public int getPerimeter() {
        return length * 4;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        Rectangle square = new Rectangle(100,100,length,length);
        g2.draw(square);


    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Main {

    static int input;
    static int length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Which shape do you want?\n1 for square\n2 for restangle\n3 for triangle\n4 for circle\n5 to exit");
            input = sc1.nextInt();
            if(input == (5)) {
                break;
            }
            if(input == (1)) {


                System.out.print("Input the length:");
                length = sc1.nextInt();
                Square mySquare = new Square();
                mySquare.getPerimeter();





                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                frame.setSize(300,400);
                frame.setTitle("ShapeViewer");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.add(mySquare);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

I also tried just putting g2.draw in the main but it wouldnt recognize g2 i kept getting an error for that.

Comment: Question:   What is the value of `Main.length` and when does it get set?   What is the value of `Square.length` and when does it get set?  What does that mean for your drawing?

Comment: the value of square.length gets set on that second scanner where it says "Input the length" and sets the user input to the variable length.

Comment: oh sorry i didnt see the rest of the question till now but i dont understand what youre asking what does it mean for my drawing? I have it so the user can choose a shape and input the length of the shape so the compiler knows this data but i just cant seem to get the shape to draw itself in the frame ive created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change you Square class. You are not initiating length for it. So it is by default 0 hence you cannot see your square. Also make it non static as every square should be different.

I have added a constructor which accepts and sets the length

```
public class Square extends JComponent{

        private int length; 

        public Square(int length) {
            this.length = length;
        }
        public double getArea() {   
        return length * length;
        }
        public int getPerimeter() {
            return length * 4;
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            Rectangle square = new Rectangle(100,100,length,length);
            g2.draw(square);


        }
    }
```

Comment: I have another question, so along with the printed square which is actually working now, i need to print below the image, text saying what the area is the name of the shape and the perimeter and as far as i know the only way to print that stuff in the frame is by using the g2.drawstring method.  but this isnt working for me because the parameters are ("string",posx,posy) and it wont accept a variable in place of a string.  i wanted to do something like g2.drawstring("Area = "+getArea(),posx,posy) but this doesnt work.

Comment: `g2.drawString("Area "+getArea(), 110, 110+length);`

I think you can use similar expression to adjust the position of your text. add the above line after `g2.draw(square);`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the Square.length is always zero. BTW, why is it static?